# Trying to create an Android Asset pack that install only on specified ABI

Tags: android, android-app-bundle, android-assetpacks

I want to create multiple android asset packs to be used in an Android App Bundle (AAB).
I want them to be downloaded and installed at app install time, but only if the target device matches a specified ABI.

I plan to create 4 asset packs, one for each supported ABI.

Asset packs are new to me, so I'm wondering if an asset pack with something like this would work (manifest for the asset pack apk)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution" package="org.some.package" split="assetsfeature">
  <dist:module dist:type="asset-pack">
    <dist:delivery>
      <dist:install-time/>
    </dist:delivery>
    <dist:conditions>
        <dist:abi dist:value="arm64-v8a" />
     </dist:conditions>
    <dist:fusing dist:include="true" />
  </dist:module>
</manifest>
```

The key thing I'm concerned about is the `dist:conditions`

```
<dist:conditions>
     <dist:abi dist:value="arm64-v8a" />
</dist:conditions>
```

Is this approach likely to work?

Comment: Why?  If you're trying to deliver a .so, consider Play Feature Delivery instead.

Comment: That's the problem, the platform specific stuff I'm delivering are not .so (otherwise I would just put them in the lib directory of the aab). Some examples are interop scripts, that are platform specific.